# How do I keep text from zooming in while turning iPhone from portrait to landscape in a web app?

Tags: mobile, web, responsive-design

I am creating my first responsive site, I am having trouble because when the iPhone is in portrait orientation, the text looks fine, but while turning to landscape, the text, images, etc all zoom in and get bigger to fit the screen. The font-size is in pixels so shouldn't it stay the same? How do I make it so it stays the same size and just adjusts the text wrap? An example of what Im trying to achieve would be this site on an iPhone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the iOS orientation bug.  There's a lot of incorrect advice out there to set a maximum scale in the viewport meta tag which seems to fix it but actually introduces a number of other issues.  You might want to look at the [workround](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/a_fix_for_the_ios_orientationchange_zoom_bug/) to see if this does what you need.